# WebStorm: 'Open in Browser' feature malfunction

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I've got following piece of example code. Simple page, using JS plugin JWPlayer to play video and one button to perform seek action in video.

```
<html>
     <head>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

          <script src="lib/js/jwplayer-7.1.4/jwplayer.js"></script>
          <script>jwplayer.key="01yIIa/jGb0bj60C14JSO8oxFHJardSr8Bn/4Q==";</script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <!-- Loading into the JWPlayer, div ID must be unique -->
          <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
          <div id="seek" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: red;"></div>

           <script type="text/javascript">
                var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
                playerInstance.setup({
                     file: "lib/video/sample.mp4",
                     controls : false
                });


                $('#seek').on('click', function() {

                     //Performs seek 10 seconds ahead

                     playerInstance.seek(playerInstance.getPosition() + 10); 
                });
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

THE PROBLEM:

Everything works fine if I open the page using full path to the file - let's say file:///C:/Users/.*/index.html. I can perform seek action. Everytime i press seek button, video moves 10seconds forward (in all browsers). BUT if I open the file using 'open in browser' feature in WebStorm - with adress let's say http://localhost:63342/.*/index.html. The seek action malfunctions in Chrome and Opera. When I press seek button in this conditions, the video starts playing over again from the start.

Any idea what this might be happening? How can these 2 even differ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of built-in webserver; please vote for [WEB-19331](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19331)